# How to play sound automatically when hovered (using div)?

Tags: html, css, hover

I am using this code:

```
 { box-sizing: border-box; }
        .specific:hover { background-image: url("example.jpg"); color:white }
```

With this code I am using this for html:

```
div class="specific"
```

With these I can easily hover over a paragraph and the background image appears instantly. But I want a little bit more like when I will hover, it should play a sound (namely mp3 file) and when I will move away the cursor the sound will stop playing and when I will hover my cursor again the sound should play from the first not from where I left it.

I have seen a lot of similar posts but the code there, I cannot put them into my file.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this very easily with an HTML audio tag with the built in JS methods, properties etc. See [this page](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_av_dom.asp). Many people don't like W3Schools much but there's good information there and it's very straight forward. It would take a very small amount of JS/jQuery utilizing a `hover` event listener with the `.play()` and `.pause()` methods to make this happen.

[Here's a simple tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_met_play.asp) using `.play()` and `.pause()`.

Comment: I used `mouseover` and `mouseout`, but that's only because I didn't feel like using jquery. :)

Comment: That certainly works @Yaakov. You definitely don't need jQuery to do this.

Answer (score 1):

I laboriously put together [a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yak613/dLxkhogy/4/) for you. But seriously, try your own stuff.

HTML

```
<div class="specific">
  Listen to some <i>music</i>...
</div>
```

JS

```
let specific = document.querySelector(".specific");
let audio = document.createElement("audio");
audio.src = "https://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-1.mp3";
document.body.appendChild(audio);

specific.onmouseover = () => {
  audio.play();
}
specific.onmouseout = () => {
    audio.pause();
}
```

You're welcome.

**UPDATE**

---

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dLxkhogy/21/

HTML

```
<div class="specific">
  <p>
    Listen to some <i>music</i>...
  </p>
</div>
<div class="specific">
  <p>
    Listen to some more music...
  </p>
</div>
<div class="specific">
  <p>
    Listen to even <i>more</i> music!
  </p>
</div>
```

JS

```
let specifics = document.querySelectorAll(".specific");

let audios = ["https://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-1.mp3", "https://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-2.mp3", "https://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-3.mp3"];

for(i = 0; i < specifics.length; i++){
    let specific = specifics[i];

  let audio = document.createElement("audio");
  audio.src = audios[i];
  document.body.appendChild(audio);

  specific.onmouseover = () => {
    audio.play();
  }
  specific.onmouseout = () => {
    audio.pause();
    audio.currentTime = 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: lol I'm sure on some wacky project in future years, I will need this. I'll come back here when I do =). Thanks for the work +1.

Comment: Thanks but like we put css at the beginning, do we put JS in the bottom? Since I'm already using .specific can I use like .sound? Then since I've used it already so: <div class="specific"> (my image file as shown above) <div="sound" >(this, my audio). Are these okay or do I put like: <div="specific" ; "sound" >? Which one is the right one? And lastly do I put something in between those brackets like: audio.pause (); ? I'm waiting for your helpful response.

Comment: Beginning of what, and bottom of what? You can put them more or less wherever you want. The rest... I have no clue what you're asking.

Comment: Man! I am so happy for all you help you are such a great person! I am so happy I am screaming I have finally done it. But just a little step, I did mentioned that the song or music should pause when I move the cursor away (it occurs successfully) but when I move my cursor back to that spot again the song or music continues instead of playing from the start again. Any workarounds on that one please?

Comment: Man just one more thing. I was searching a lot of places for this but couldn't find. I have used this javascript formula: <script> [exactly the JS code you wrote] </script>. So this is what I used. And I am successfully able to play songs on hover. But there are many places where I have to play different sounds. So I created more of your JS code with <script> & </script> but one thing I noticed is that, only the first JS code applies, the ones that are below this, they do not work. So what to do?

Comment: I'm on my phone now, once I get on my computer I'll figure it out.

Comment: I really love this man but I can see that you've used the same image for all three paragraphs. But I'll be using different images so do I just add more image urls using  commas or semi colons in the css code? Is this the way to do so? If not please for the last time get me right.